# How do you type a useState hook that is being passed as a prop to a component, typescript+react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two components
 and

Now I'm passing a useState hook from Admin component into the Login component as a setAuth prop

In my Admin component:

```
const Admin = () => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  <Login setAuth={setAuth} />
}
```

And my Login component:

```
const Login = ({ setAuth }) => {
  //and then logic to set auth based on db auth from firebase
  setAuth(true)
}
```

How do I properly type the setState hook being passed as a prop to a component?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ISetAuth {
  setAuth: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const Login = ({ setAuth }: ISetAuth) => {
  //whatever code
}
```

Comment: Few improvements: 1st the interface for the props should be named after a component rather then 1 of the props. so it should be `ILoginProps` rather then `ISetAuth`. Its not a requirement but rather a convention. 2nd typing `Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>` takes a lot of key strokes, its long and ugly. While it is correct, you could also just simply type `(auth: boolean) => void`. This also makes a component more reusable as of right now you can not only pass in a setState hook but ANY function.

Comment: Although the end result may the same, by convention components should notify their parents of change, as opposed to accepting a function to mutate the state. IMO the naming should look more like: `<Login onAuthChange={setAuth} />` and the `onAuthChange` would be `(auth: boolean) => void`

Comment: Yeah guys, I really don't care... This was for a very small app, it's a setState hook being passed down to one component, this interface is only for this hook, and go try the lazy typed way you're using and see if it works, Dummkopf ;)
@Lith